# somewhat hidden 2d acceleration on modern cards

Tags: winapi, opengl, 2d, nvidia

As far as It is talked modern cards mainly support 3d graphisc 
hardware acceleration (on top of it ogl and dx interfaces are build)

Some say almost that it is the only real way to use graphics 
on modern cards and it is really no way to do classicakl 2d
graphics on modern cards

The last must be false I think, because say for eample windows
desktop is an example of some (out of 3d) 2d mode, I do not think 
it is really an orthogonal projection 2d textyred quad - but this mode 
is 'out of' open gl and direct x

I had read somewhere some small info that this somewhat mysterious 2d 
mode is even in some extend hardware accelerated (but somewhat poorly and 
it varies on nvidia and ati)

My question is how to get much more info about this mysteruious
2d mode and acceleration? In what extent there exist such one? 
How to use it?

(I would like to find out about and use such 2d hardware acceleration 
to maximal extent in writing 2d graphics on windows especialy through 
some 'open' interface  )

(maybe last direct2d has something to do with it, but I have read some 
critics about direct2d (and to be honest I do not like directx, 
I am closer to be open gl guy and I  want to do extremmaly fast 
accelerated 2d on PC/win)

1. is there some *2d* mode on modern cards or even windows desktop is a quad texture in 3d?
2. if so how to use *2d* mode (and even 2d acceleration) on modern cards, especialy in cooperation with open gl (without directx and so)?

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172661). If you have specific *programming* questions, we'll be glad to try and help answer them. For generic "can you tell me about" questions, try Google. :-)

Comment: It is specific question, 'how to use such hidden 2d mode/acceleration ' - it must exist (window desktop uses it' but it is terribly obscure

Comment: It's not specific. It's no more specific than "how do I write an operating system" would be; it's a generic "please educate me about something" question. This is also not a discussion site, link source, or search engine. Specific questions are about actually writing code or using libraries, not "please teach me general graphics programming". Sorry you don't agree, but I think it's not an actual question for here and I've voted to close it as such. If 4 others agree, it will be closed; if they don't, it will stay open. :-)

Comment: You coul say it (that it is generic, and SO is not search engine) about any question for example 'how to use somthing' IMO it is a good question (I want to say how can I use such 2d acceleration '

Comment: I'm not arguing or discussing it with you any further. I could also have downvoted it as a poor question; I chose not to do so. My opinion about whether or not it's a proper question is what determines my vote, and I've already expressed that opinion by voting to close this question. Your debating it is not going to change my vote, and this is not a chat room.

Comment: I agree your answers has zero value in subject As to my question it is good becouse it is not easy to find such obscure subject in google or so, This 2d mode is somewhat obscured IMO - so it is IMO more valuable than common simple questions

Comment: @user982377 "As to my question it is good becouse it is not easy to find such obscure subject in google or so" FYI: that's not how a question is defined as "good or bad." A good question is one that fits the site. A bad question is once that doesn't. Personally, I disagree with Ken that this question doesn't fit the site (though it is at best marginal in doing so).

Comment: It is maybe a matter of formulating (stating) it not the question itself,

Answer (score 1):

There is no "mysterious 2d mode" in graphics cards. If you're talking about advanced compositing systems like AeroGlass and so forth, that's all done with 3D rendering. As you put it, "an orthogonal projection 2d textyred quad". They may also do some special operations on the CPU.

Direct2D itself is little more than adding more to that. It has some CPU components, but all of its GPU components are ultimately just some form of triangle rendering, likely with a texture and some form of framebuffer blending.

Comment: I do not blelive it. It is untrue, as far as i know. I have read somewhere that there is 2d mode and windows uses it, it is even accelerated

Comment: If you have "read somewhere" that this is not the case, then please add your sources to your question. Otherwise we can't discuss it. But yeah, I would agree that there is no such mysterious mode.

Comment: see http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/2d-windows-gdi,2539.html  i do not fully understand it (i am not much experienced) and all topic of 2d acceleration is obscure As I said (sorry to state it but i see that SO is getting wacky, specially good questions are downwoted)

Comment: @user982377: A question isn't good just because you decide it is. The community decides what is and isn't good. As for the link you provide, that's talking about GDI functions, which are part of the Windows GDI and Windows driver model. They are implemented by drivers, which are usually converted into *3D drawing commands*. There is no 2D mode; it's simply calling into the driver, who makes the appropriate 3D calls to the hardware.

Comment: it is about 2d hardware acceleration, so if it is about hardware it is not only about gdi ;-) and if it is about 2d hardware acceleration it is not about 3D hardware acceleration

Comment: @user982377: Your problem is your belief that 2D and 3D acceleration are *different*. They aren't. And the article is about 2D acceleration *through* the GDI. That's what it discusses and that's what it benchmarks.

Comment: Yes, Tour problem is your belief that 2d and 3d acceleration are not differend - I think that 2d windows desktop (including for example rendering true type fonts) is not a textured quead in 3d (it is mysterious 2d mode 'out of' 3d enggine and I want to know how to get to it), same for BIOS video screen

Comment: I'm sorry, but Nicol Bolas's knowledge reaches a bit farther than mere belief. You seem to be so set on discovering a magical 2D mode you can tap into that you won't take 'no' for an answer. Well, then go ahead and find it. If you do, please make it into an answer here. We would all love to hear about it.

Comment: @user982377: The BIOS executes outside of the OS environment by directly accessing the hardware. It's running under the old VESA and prior video systems. Your programs are running under the OS, which will not allow you access to that most ancient of hardware.

Comment: @ups, So You 're _SURE_ that windows desktop is only a QUAD TEXTURE like you wolud simulate 2d graphics in OpenGL ??? Sounds crazy. How would be this things done, rambufer and uploading texture to GPU?? It is to crazy, can you show me some proof of it by citation or so

Comment: I have read something and it shows up that some up Vista windows uses triangles and quad texture to make windows desktop, but it writes (i do not full understand it) that for example logging screen is done in different way not and also xp desktop also - how about that?